# Pyspark dot product of a DF and a dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I'd like to have a dot product of a DF (multiple columns) and a dictionary with keys matching some of the column names and values that should be used as weights. Here is an example:

```
dic = {'SG_actions': 1, 'SO_actions': 2, 'GS_actions': 3}
```

df =

```
__________________________________________________
| Ag |  SG_actions | SO_actions  | GS_actions     |
|____|_____________|_____________|________________|
| 1  |       2     |       0     |       0        |
| 1  |       0     |       1     |       1        |
| 2  |       1     |       1     |       1        |
|____|_____________|_____________|________________|
```

Output:

```
__________________________________________________________
| Ag |  SG_actions | SO_actions  | GS_actions  |  New col  |
|____|_____________|_____________|_____________|___________|
| 1  |       2     |       0     |       0     |     2     |
| 1  |       0     |       1     |       1     |     5     |
| 2  |       1     |       1     |       1     |     6     |
|____|_____________|_____________|_____________|___________|
```

**Note**: I'm using Spark 3.1, and I can't upgrade to 3.2 to use spark.pandas library.

This is the code in python:

```
df["new_col"] = df[df[list(dic.keys())].dot(pd.Series(dic))]
```

I need to build a pyspark version.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please check my answer which uses UDF function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a UDF function in Pyspark to achieve this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# create original dataframe
data = [
    (1, 2, 0, 0),
    (1, 0, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 1, 1)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Ag", "SG_actions", "SO_actions", "GS_actions"])
df.show()
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# | Ag|SG_actions|SO_actions|GS_actions|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# |  1|         2|         0|         0|
# |  1|         0|         1|         1|
# |  2|         1|         1|         1|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+

# The dict to calculate dot product
dic = {'SG_actions': 1, 'SO_actions': 2, 'GS_actions': 3}

# Create an UDF function to calculate dot prodcut based on df and dict
# 1,1,1 => 1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3 = 6
def dot_product(row, dic):
    return sum([row[col] * dic[col] for col in dic.keys() if col in row])

dot_product_udf = udf(lambda row: dot_product(row, dic), IntegerType())

# Apply the UDF function to the 'New col' column
df = df.withColumn('New col', dot_product_udf(struct([col for col in df.columns])))
df.show()
# +---+----------+----------+----------+-------+
# | Ag|SG_actions|SO_actions|GS_actions|New col|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+-------+
# |  1|         2|         0|         0|      2|
# |  1|         0|         1|         1|      5|
# |  2|         1|         1|         1|      6|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```